# Setting application-wide default fonts tkinter root window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to a create an optionDB file which should be of the type.Xdefaults in order to read into a Python Tkinter program to override the Windows system fonts. The idea was presented in the Tkinter book by Grayson on page 49.

1) Create a file called optionDB of type Xdefaults

2) type in the following code

```
root = Tk()
root.option_readfile('optionDB')
```

At this point, a new font should override the system default.

The optionDB file has the following line of code in it  -

```
*font: Verdana 10
```

I cannot read the file for the following reason -
Notepad keeps appending a .txt - I have tried optionDB which removes .txt but still cannot find the files even if just named optionDB with no file extension.

**Question:**

How do I create a  '?Xdeaults' file ad read it correctly through the above code.
I have tried typing 'optionDB.Xdefaults' as well, and in all cases Tkinter returned a cannot open file error.

Comment: This is the error messageFile "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 659, in option_readfile
    self.tk.call('option', 'readfile', fileName, priority)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "optionDB": no such file or directory
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the file anything you want -- the .txt is harmless. Just make sure that you give the actual filename to `option_readfile`.

```
root.option_readfile('optionDB.txt')
```

Like with just about any file argument, python will look in the current working directory unless you specifically tell it to look somewhere else.