# What is optionDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a `toplevel widget` in `tkinter`, but it gives me an error when I run the program. The traceback will direct me towards the optionDB, indicating that it isn't in my directory --which is true. Where can I download or find the `optionDB`, and what exactly is it? I also searched the web, but I couldn't find a good answer. I hope someone can help me with this.

There may be other ways of creating a `toplevel widget`, but I also want to know what an optionDB is. I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner and I don't know enough yet.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.option_readfile("optionDB")
root.title("Toplevel")
```

Traceback:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "optionDB": no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the name suggests optionDB stores all the options like font and so. and generally loaded as follows: It seems either you don't have the file or file is not in the path.
For now you can create an empty file in the path and see if it moves further.

[Setting application-wide default fonts tkinter root window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022777/setting-application-wide-default-fonts-tkinter-root-window)

Other option related methods available

```
 |  option_add(self, pattern, value, priority=None)
 |      Set a VALUE (second parameter) for an option
 |      PATTERN (first parameter).
 |
 |      An optional third parameter gives the numeric priority
 |      (defaults to 80).
 |
 |  option_clear(self)
 |      Clear the option database.
 |
 |      It will be reloaded if option_add is called.
 |
 |  option_get(self, name, className)
 |      Return the value for an option NAME for this widget
 |      with CLASSNAME.
 |
 |      Values with higher priority override lower values.
 |
 |  option_readfile(self, fileName, priority=None)
 |      Read file FILENAME into the option database.
 |
 |      An optional second parameter gives the numeric
 |      priority.
```

Comment: Goodness! Thank you so much. I actually just created an optionDB.txt file; changed my code to root.option_readfile('optionDB.txt'), and it worked!